# Liberty Profile server executing incorrect function on request

Tags: spring-mvc, websphere-liberty

Preface: I don't have this issue with Tomcat or Tomee server.

I'm trying to execute a simple Get request through ajax, when the request hits the server it executes the wrong method.

JS file

```
function CustomerPoints() {
        this.initializeListeners = function () {
            $("#storeSelect").change(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                customerPoints.callAjax(contextPath + "/loyaltyPoints/customerPoints?getPoints&id=" + $("#storeSelect").val());
            });

        this.callAjax = function (url, value) {
            // generated url = http://localhost:9080/TLC/loyaltyPoints/customerPoints?getPoints&id=3778
            var cardNumber = $("#customerNumber");
            var alternateId = $("#alternateId");
            $
                .ajax(
                url,
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    data: value,
                    beforeSend: function (req) {
                        $("#modalErrorDiv").empty();
                        req.setRequestHeader("Accept",
                            "text/html;type=ajax");
                        req.setRequestHeader($(
                            "meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr(
                            "content"), $("meta[name='_csrf']")
                            .attr("content"));
                    },
                    complete: function (jqXHR) {
                        $("#customerNumber").replaceWith(cardNumber);
                        $("#alternateId").replaceWith(alternateId);
                        customerPoints.initializeListeners();
                    },
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $("#content").replaceWith(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $('body').offset().top
                        }, 'slow');
                        $("#modalErrorDiv").empty();
                        $("#modalErrorDiv")
                            .append("<ul ><li class='error'>An error has occured. Please contact support.</li></ul>");
                    }
                });
        };
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class CustomerPointsController
{
    private static final String HTML_PAGE          = "loyaltyPoints/customerPoints";
    private static final String REQUESTMAPPING     = "/" + HTML_PAGE;
    private static final String APPLYPOINTSMAPPING = "loyaltyPoints/applyPoints :: #content";
    private static final String CONTENT            = HTML_PAGE + " :: #content";

    /**
     * @param model
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = REQUESTMAPPING)
    public String maintainCustomerPoints(Model model)
    {
        // this is the method that is called everytime
        return HTML_PAGE;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     * @param model
     * @returns the valid customer points for this store, default followed by promotion points
     * when a user picks a store from the drop down.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = REQUESTMAPPING, method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {
            "getPoints"})
    public String getPoints(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id, Model model)
    {
        // this is the method that never gets called
        return CONTENT;
    }
}
```

Note I also took the generated URL from the page script and pasted into my browser to execute. It only executes `maintainCustomerPoints`.

server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="tlc server">
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jsf-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>json-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>beanValidation-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>monitor-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>
  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" virtualHost="default_host" />
  <jdbcDriver id="DerbyJDBCDriver">
    <library name="DerbyLib">
      <fileset dir="C:\tools\servers\wlp\lib" includes="derbyclient-10.6.1.0.jar" />
    </library>
  </jdbcDriver>
  <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/TLCDataSource" id="derbyDataSource" jdbcDriverRef="DerbyJDBCDriver">
    <properties.derby.client databaseName="TLC" password="APP" user="APP" />
  </dataSource>
  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
  <application id="TLC_war" context-root="/TLC" location="C:\Users\nd26434\gitrepos\tlc\target\TLC-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" name="TLC_war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
      <privateLibrary>
        <fileset dir="C:\tools\servers\wlp\lib" includes="aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar" />
      </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
  </application>
</server>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity could you try to call it via `customerPoints?getPoints=1` to add some random value to your `getPoints` param. As looking at the [RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) it might require some value.

Comment: Thanks @Gas that did the trick. If you want to enter that as an answer. I'll approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) `@RequestMapping`, if has `params` in the `{"myParam"}` form, assumes that such parameter has to be present in the request and may have any value.

So the safe form of the URL should contain any value for `getPoints` like `customerPoints?getPoints=anyValueHere`.

Probably the `request.getParameter()` method returns different value for Tomcat, when no value is present. For Liberty it return `null` if there is no `=` , like `customerPoints?getPoints` and `non null` when there is `=` like `customerPoints?getPoints=`